# Modifying the default behaviour of a Vue Cli 3 project test runner

Tags: visual-studio-code, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I am very new to this style of workflow, so please don't assume much in the answers.

I have started a new project using Vue CLI 3 creation tools, and including the Mocha-Chai tests. I can run the tests in Yarn (`yarn run test:unit`)

I would like to know:

1. How might I attach a debugger to the test run (I am using Visual Studio Code)?
2. How might I run the tests in a browser?